# Using this() of a constructor to call another constructor in the same class in Java

Tags: java, constructor

A small segment of testing code as follows:

```
class Teacher {
    private String title;
    String name = "A";
    int age = 20;

    Teacher (String title) {
        //System.out.println(name);
        this(name,age,title);
    }

    Teacher (String name, int age, String title) {
        System.out.println("OK");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Teacher teacher1 = new Teacher("John");
        Teacher teacher2 = new Teacher("Mike",25,"TA");
    }
}
```

As above, I annotated `System.out.println(name);` After compiling, there was an error:`Can't reference name(age) before the superclass constructor has been called.` However, I annotated  `this(name,age,title);`, which meant I only used `System.out.println(name);`. And the error was gone. Thus, I think the `name` and `age` has been initialized and get the value `A`,`20`. That is to say, `this(name,age,title)` is actually `this("a",20,"John")` I don't know the principle. Need your help.

Comment: It may not be linked to the problem, but you should declare both constructors as `public`.

Comment: You have to call the constructor before calling anything else when overloading.

Comment: would `new Teacher("John");` be setting his title to john and not his name

Answer (score 1):

Java Documentation says that

> If present, the invocation of another constructor must be the first line in the constructor.

Comment: THX,I think it's because every class you defined inherits from the Object class. And when I use this() function to call another constructor , the super(name,age) function in that constructor cannot be executed for var name and age haven't been initialized yet. And in other words, before the execution of superclass' constructor, the vars of subclass cannot be initialized , so you cannot call this(name,age,"professor").

Comment: accept any answer so that,someone looking for an answer to same problem can get the solution easily

Answer (score 1):

this/super constructor call has to be the first statement when you chain constructor call. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) for details.

Comment: THX,I think it's because every class you defined inherits from the Object class. And when I use this() function to call another constructor , the super(name,age) function in that constructor cannot be executed for var name and age haven't been initialized yet. And in other words, before the execution of superclass' constructor, the vars of subclass cannot be initialized , so you cannot call this(name,age,"professor").

Answer (score 1):

The principle is,

> If present, the invocation of another constructor must be the first
>   line in the constructor.

Reference : [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Using `this` keyword you are invoking other constructor.
When you comment out the first statement, the constructor call becomes first line which is legal.

Comment: THX,I think it's because every class you defined inherits from the Object class. And when I use this() function to call another constructor , the super(name,age) function in that constructor cannot be executed for var name and age haven't been initialized yet. And in other words, before the execution of superclass' constructor, the vars of subclass cannot be initialized , so you cannot call this(name,age,"professor").

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the fields `name` and `age` when calling `this()`. The fields have not been initialized yet. If you want name to be "A" by default and age to be 20, enter the values directly as parameters to `this()`.

The following class will compile:

```
class Teacher {
    private String title;
    String name;
    int age;

    Teacher (String title) {
        this("A",20,title);
    }

    Teacher (String name, int age, String title) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        System.out.println("OK");
    }
}
```

Comment: THX,I think it's because every class you defined inherits from the Object class. And when I use this() function to call another constructor , the super(name,age) function in that constructor cannot be executed for var name and age haven't been initialized yet. And in other words, before the execution of superclass' constructor, the vars of subclass cannot be initialized , so you cannot call this(name,age,"professor").